# jQuery function .one is not woking

Tags: javascript, jquery

Every time I click the add icon, the addFunction() in javascript file invokes. And each time the function invokes, it attaches a click function to the unordered list.

To avoid attachment of multiple click functions I used .one instead of .on but this approach is not working.

HTML:

```
ul#classesAndSubjectsList
    each value, index in user.classesAndSubjects
       li !{value}
a.ml-4#classesAndSubjects(href='javascript:;')
    i.fa.fa-plus(aria-hidden="true")
```

Javascript:

```
addFunction = function() {
    const txt = prompt(promptMsg1, promptMsg2);
    if (!(txt == null || txt == "")) {

        const i = document.createElement("i");
        i.classList.add("fa");
        i.classList.add("fa-times");
        i.classList.add('red-cross');

        const a = document.createElement("a");
        a.classList.add("ml-4");
        a.append(i);

        const t = document.createTextNode(txt)

        const newItem = document.createElement("li");
        newItem.append(t);
        newItem.append(a);

        var final = $("ul#classesAndSubjectsList");
        // No idea why .one is not working
        final.one('click', 'li a', function () {
            //other code
        });
        $(final).append(newItem);
     }
 }

 $("a#classesAndSubjects").click(function(){
      addFunction();
 });
```

Comment: one place you do `final.one` and another you do `$(final).append`, maybe that gives you a clue, try `$(final).one`

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: With the unordered list, more than one click function get attached. I just want single click function.